# AttributeError: 'game' object has no attribute ''

Tags: python, attributes

AttributeError: 'game' object has no attribute 'uValue'
Can someone help me with my spaghetti code?
When I run my program I want to add the hit card value to self.uValue (my total hand value for the user). Although I get the error listed above and an identical one for the (self.TotalC) (total cards in the hand). I also have issues keeping the value set in the Usercards method for self.uValue. Even though i return the value every time i wish to print the value it is said it equals zero other then when i print it inside the method.

```
class game():
  def __init__(self):
      self.TotalC = 2 # total cards in the hand

  def Usercards(self):
      UC1= cards() # defining both objects
      UC2= cards()
      UC1.deck() # defingin each card
      UC2.deck()
      uHand.remove("deal")  # removes deal from the hand allowing the user to start hitting
      card1v=int(UC1.value)  # the value of the card is equal to the self.value of it
      card1s=UC1.suit     # the suit of the card is definined as a varible from self.suit of the call class
      card2v=int(UC2.value)        # same for the second card
      card2s=UC2.suit
      type=UC1.num # type of the card is defined from the call class (self.num) example: (ace, 2, king , 5)
      card1 = Image(Point(300,350), (card1s+type+".gif")) # graphics deinfed where to draw and what to draw
      card1.draw(win) # draws image
      type=UC2.num #type of second card
      card2 = Image(Point(225,350), (card2s+type+".gif")) # graphics defined for the second card
      card2.draw(win) # draws second card
      self.uValue= card1v + card2v # add the value varibles for both cards
      print(self.uValue) # prints value
      self.TotalC = 2
      return card1v, card1s, card2v, card2s,uHand, self.uValue #reurtns card suits and values and hand

  def AIhand(self):
      back = Image(Point(225, 150),("back.gif"))
      back.draw(win)
      AIC1= cards()
      AIC1.deck()
      AIcard1v=int(AIC1.value)  # the value of the card is equal to the self.value of it
      #second card (visible one)
      AIC2= cards()
      AIC2.deck()
      AIcard2v=int(AIC2.value)  # the value of the card is equal to the self.value of it
      AIcard2s=AIC2.suit     # the suit of the card is definined as a varible from self.suit of the call class
      AItype2=AIC2.num # type of the card is defined from the call class (self.num) example: (ace, 2, king , 5)
      AIcard2 = Image(Point(300,150), (AIcard2s+AItype2+".gif")) # graphics defined for the second card
      AIcard2.draw(win) # draws second card
      self.AIvalue = AIcard2v + AIcard1v
      print(self.AIvalue)
      return self.AIvalue, AIHand  # AI2 = "{}{}".format(AIC2.suit, AIC2.num)

  def wincon(self):
      if self.uValue>AIHV:
          print("You win")
          uHand.append("deal")
      else:
          print("You lose")
          uHand.append("deal")

  def UHit(self):
      HC1 = cards()
      HC1.deck()
      value = int(HC1.value)
      suit = HC1.suit
      type = HC1.num
      print (self.uValue)
      if self.TotalC==2:
          card1 = Image(Point(375, 350), (suit + type +".gif"))
          card1.draw(win)
      elif self.TotalC==3:
          card1 = Image(Point(450, 350), (suit + type + ".gif"))
          card1.draw(win)
      elif self.TotalC==4:
          card1 = Image(Point(450, 375), (suit + type + ".gif"))
          card1.draw(win)
```

Comment: This seems incomplete, what does the `class` look like? These are the functions for the said class, I'm guessing.

Comment: The class definition is above the code block. I dont have edit privs btw.

Comment: But yes it seems incomplete. Please post a runnable script, like by adding `if __name__ == '__main__':`: block at the bottom.

Comment: Please see how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)